# How can I get the name of the column if the value ends with specific string from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple csv files I need to figure out which column name contain a date-timestamp value which ends with 000Z. For the df below it is LastModifiedUtc. The idea is to upload a csv file so in retun I get the columname which ends with 000Z.

df= OrgUnitId  UserId   ToolName   LastModifiedUtc              LastModifiedBy ActivityExemptionsLogId
         35461   24878  Grades     2020-01-24T09:09:07.1930000Z          26701                     149
         35461   24878  Grades     2020-01-24T08:55:05.2330000Z          26701                     148

Can somebody help me ?

Answer (score 0):

through df.select_dtypes you can filter a dataframe by only the columns with the given data type. 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html

Have a look in your data for which data type you need:

```
df.dtypes
```

Maybe you need to replace 'datetime64' with 'datetime64[ns, UTC]', depending on what exact dtype you are looking for. Then if you have only 1 column with datetime values, you can use the following to get the name of that column

```
df.select_dtypes(include=['datetime64']).columns.values[0]
```